# Does the following have a design pattern?

Tags: php, design-patterns

I feel like there's a design pattern for this problem, but I can't seem to find the proper one.

I have a Server class that has what you might call 3 *processes* to run, and then output a result. Each process has a list of "plugins" that all run at every process. Each plugin(class) has a constant, that is the name of the plugin. So it looks something like this:

```
<?php
// Simplified Server class.
class Server {
  protected $format = array();
  protected $service = array();
  protected $handler = array();

  public function addFormat($class, $name = '') {
    if ($name === FALSE) {
      $name = $class::NAME;
    }
    $this->formats[$name] = $class;
    return $this;
  }
  public function getFormat($name) {
    if (is_string($this->formats[$name])) {
      $this->formats[$name] = new $this->formats[$name]($this);
    }
    return $this->formats[$name];
  }

  // And then these 2 functions are repeated 2 times, one for each of the other processes.
  // So I got a addServer, getService, addHandler, getHandler function now.

  public function processEverything($service, $handler, $format) {
    $output = $this->getService($service)->getOutput();
    $this->getHandler($handler)->handle($output);
    return $this->getFormat($format)->format($output);
  }
}

// The Format base class.
abstract class FormatBase {
  const NAME = '';

  abstract public function format($output);
}

// There's also 2 other base classes, that both have the NAME constant, but different
// abstract functions.

// A simple Format class
class UppercaseFormat extends FormatBase {
  const NAME = 'test_format';

  public function format($output) {
    return strtoupper($output);
  }
}
```

Can I cram this into a design pattern, it feels wrong to do all that copying and pasting for my functions in Server.

And please do tell me if I need to elaborate on anything.

Comment: It has some similarities with strategy.

Comment: [`command` with `active object` pattern](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-whens-and-whys-for-php-design-patterns--net-27862)?